# How do I select MySQL Data that are from next year

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I am working on a file management project, where I have expiry dates for every file. I need to list all the files that are going to expire the next year. What will be the SQL query?

should it be something like:

```
$date = date ('Y-m-j');
$newdate = strtotime ( '+1 year' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
$newdate = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $newdate );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE `expDate` = year ($newdate)" ;
```

Comment: what is the data type of `expDate` ?

Comment: @YohanesGultom, date(yyyy-mm-dd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE YEAR(`expDate`) = YEAR(NOW()) + 1" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `expDate` is in mysql timestamp(`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`) , you can use this

```
 DATE_ADD(`expDate`, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysql DATE_ADD to add years

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE `expDate` = YEAR(DATE_ADD($date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR))";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$newdate = date ( 'Y-m-j' , strtotime('+1 year') );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE `expDate` = year ($newdate)" ;
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE `expDate` = YEAR(NOW())+1;
```